# How to convert all the fields with another table

Tags: sql-server, select, inner-join, multiple-tables

I'm using SQL Server.
I would like to "translate" all the returned values by using another table.

The "WORK" table looks like this :

```
Id |item1 |item2 |item3 |item4 |item5 |item6 |item7 |item8 |item9 |item10
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1019 | 3009 | 4014 | 3001 | 4005 | 4019 | 4006 | 2021 |(NULL)|(NULL)
 2 | 1019 | 3009 | 4014 | 3001 | 4005 | 3012 | 4019 | 4006 | 2021 |(NULL)
 3 | 1019 | 3009 | 4014 | 3002 | 4004 | 4018 | 4006 | 2021 |(NULL)|(NULL)
 4 | 1019 | 3009 | 4014 | 3001 | 4005 | 3012 | 4019 | 4006 | 2021 |(NULL)
```

And the conversion table "EQUIPEMENT" :

```
 Id  | Name
-------------
1018 | C18
1019 | TVR1
2018 | C18
2021 | CAMION
3000 | E1
3001 | E2
3002 | E3
3009 | TCR1
3010 | TCR2
3011 | NETT
3012 | EM
4004 | B2D5
4005 | B2D6
4006 | B2D7
4014 | B2D15
4019 | P306B
```

Then I query this : `SELECT * FROM WORK WHERE Id=1`

I would like to get this :

```
1 | TVR1 | TCR1 | B2D15 | E2 | B2D6 | P306B | B2D7 | CAMION |(NULL)|(NULL)
```

Not doubt that we have to use some JOIN... or?
I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Bye :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this can be done using [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), followed by a `LEFT JOIN` and then by `PIVOT`, a more adequate solution would be to normalize your data first.

In classic relational database design, your "*WORK*" table would have 3 columns:

1. A unique identifier (`id`)
2. A "groupping key" (`group`)
3. Data (`item_id`)

You'd then simply `JOIN` this table with the "*EQUIPMENT*" table, and handle presentation in a presentation layer that takes care of "un-pivoting".

Comment: Thank you very much @Amit ! By changing the design it is so easier to make a simple request :  `SELECT * FROM TRAVAIL INNER JOIN EQUIPEMENT ON TRAVAIL.I_Id = EQUIPEMENT.P_Id `